# phonegap 2.0 - navigator.camera.getPicture exceptions when user selects a non-photo

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, gallery

I have updated `PhoneGap` from `version 1.9.0 to 2.0.0`, but on choosing a picture from gallery the android app crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=17, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5688508227233513282 }} to activity {com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to solve this.

Is there a way to catch the exception gracefully?
How can we ensure that the users only choose images?